# Mac 2011 using some functions in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have recently transferred a working set of routines from Windows Excel 2003 and tried to run them in Excel for Mac 2011. It fails on the first attempt to use the left function. With the error message "cannot find project or library". I have tried setting up a test function to run various text functions and things like Len work but neither left right or mid. The routine is the start of a process to handle  exported Access data. Do not think that is relevant as the routine does not start because of the problem with left.

This is my test code.

```
Function testfunctions()

Dim carrier, carrier2

carrier = "Alpha1"

carrier2 = Left(carrier, Len(carrier) - 4)
MsgBox carrier

End Function
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove an errant space in this line (yours)

```
carrier 2 = Left(carrier, Len(carrier) - 4)
```

Change to this:

```
carrier2 = Left(carrier, Len(carrier) - 4)
```

Comment: My Mistake and I fixed that no luck. However I have now discovered I have to tell Excel it is a VBA function this works.
Function testfunctions()
carrier = "Aplha1"
carrier2 = VBA.Left(carrier, 4)
MsgBox carrier2

End Function
Thanks for taking the time to reply. I can see the change to Excel for Mac is not going to be that easy.

Comment: What references are checked when you go to Tools>References in the VBA window?